# Bootstrap toggle disappears when paginating using Jquery DataTable

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I am working on an application that manages the presence of participants at an event. I have a problem with the bootstrap toggle. I'm using it in a Jquery datatable. As soon as I change the page to go to the next page with the arrows of the table the toggle disappears i have just a white checkbox. I have the impression that it does not reload when the new page is loaded. Somebody would have a solution to this problem. I put the captures of the bugs in attachments.

Thanks in advance.

Bootstrap Toogle:

[image: Bootstrap Toogle]

DEMO

```html
<?php include 'admin/db_connect.php' ?>
<?php 
$event = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM events where md5(id) = '{$_GET['c']}'")->fetch_array();
foreach($event as $k => $v){
    $$k = $v;
}

?>
 <div class="content-header">
      <div class="container-md">
        <div class="row mb-2">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h1 class="m-0"><?php echo ucwords($event)." Event" ?></h1>
          </div><!-- /.col -->

        </div><!-- /.row -->
            <hr class="border-primary">
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </div>

<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="card card-outline card-primary">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <div class="card-tools d-flex justify-content-end" style="width: calc(40%)">
                            <a class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-default btn-flat border-primary col-sm-4 mr-2" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="location.reload()"><i class="fa fa-redo"></i> Rafraîchir</a>
                            <?php if($status != 2): ?>
                            <!--<a class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-default btn-flat border-primary new_attendee m-0 col-sm-4" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Nouveau participant</a>-->
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <?php if($status == 2): ?>
                            <div class="alert alert-info"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> L'inscription et la participation à l'événement sont désormais closes. </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <table class="table table-bordered">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>#</th>
                                    <th>Noms & prénoms</th>
                                    <th>Sexe</th>
                                    <th>Email</th>
                                    <th>Participation</th>
                                    <th>Action</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <?php
                                $i = 1;
                                $qry = $conn->query("SELECT a.*,concat(a.lastname,', ',a.firstname,' ',a.middlename) as name,e.event FROM attendees a inner join events e on e.id = a.event_id where e.id = $id order by unix_timestamp(e.date_created) desc ");
                                while($row= $qry->fetch_assoc()):
                                ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="text-center"><?php echo $i++ ?></th>
                                    <td><b><?php echo ucwords($row['name']) ?></b></td>
                                    <td><b><?php echo ucwords($row['gender']) ?></b></td>
                                    <td><b><?php echo $row['email'] ?></b></td>
                                    <td class="text-center">
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="status_chk" id="" data-bootstrap-switch data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Present" data-off="Waiting" class="switch-toggle status_chk" data-size="xs" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" data-width="5rem" data-id='<?php echo $row['id'] ?>' <?php echo $row['status'] == '1' ? 'checked' : '' ?>>
                                    </td>
                                    
                                    <td class="text-center">
                                        <div class="btn-group">
                                            <?php if($status != 2): ?>
                                            <button href="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat edit_attendee" data-id="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"> 
                                              <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
                                            </button>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                             <button href="button" class="btn btn-info btn-flat view_attendee" data-id="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">
                                              <i class="fas fa-eye"></i>
                                            </button>
                                            <?php if($status != 2): ?>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-flat delete_attendee" data-id="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">
                                              <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
                                            </button>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                      </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>   
                             <?php endwhile; ?>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    
    $(document).ready(function(){
        
        $('.view_attendee').click(function(){
            uni_modal("Détails du participant","view_attendee.php?id="+$(this).attr('data-id'))
        })
        $('.new_attendee').click(function(){
            uni_modal("Nouveau participant","manage_attendee.php?event_id=<?php echo $id ?>","mid-large")
        })
        $('.edit_attendee').click(function(){
            uni_modal("Modifier les détails du participant","manage_attendee.php?id="+$(this).attr('data-id')+"&event_id=<?php echo $id ?>","mid-large")
        })
        $('.delete_attendee').click(function(){
        _conf("Êtes-vous sûr de supprimer ce participant ?","delete_attendee",[$(this).attr('data-id')])
        })
        
        $('.status_chk').change(function(){
            var status = $(this).prop('checked') == true ? 1 : 2;
            if($(this).attr('data-state-stats') !== undefined && $(this).attr('data-state-stats') == 'error'){
                $(this).removeAttr('data-state-stats')
                return false;
            }
            var _this = $(this)
            // return false;
            var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
            start_load()
            $.ajax({
                url:'admin/ajax.php?action=update_attendee_stats',
                method:'POST',
                data:{id:id,status:status},
                error:function(err){
                    console.log(err)
                    alert_toast("Something went wrong while updating the attendee's status.",'error')
                        _this.attr('data-state-stats','error').bootstrapToggle('toggle')
                        end_load()
                },
                success:function(resp){
                    if(resp == 1){
                        alert_toast("attendee status successfully updated.",'success')
                        end_load()
                    }else if(resp == 2){
                        alert_toast("Event Registration and Attendance is close.",'error')
                        _this.attr('data-state-stats','error').bootstrapToggle('toggle')
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            location.reload()
                        },2000)
                    }else{
                        alert_toast("Something went wrong while updating the attendee's status.",'error')
                        _this.attr('data-state-stats','error').bootstrapToggle('toggle')
                        end_load()
                    }
                }
            })
        })
        
        $('table').dataTable()
    })
    
    function delete_attendee($id){
        start_load()
        $.ajax({
            url:'admin/ajax.php?action=delete_attendee',
            method:'POST',
            data:{id:$id},
            success:function(resp){
                if(resp==1){
                    alert_toast("Data successfully deleted",'success')
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        location.reload()
                    },1500)

                }
            }
        })
    }
    
    
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like your problem is in this file:

```
admin/ajax.php?action=update_attendee_stats
```

can you share the script here?